# Extract sentences with numbers in it

Tags: python, string

I am trying to extract sentence segments with numbers in it. For example, the string

> "This is a sentence with numbers, and this is not a sentence with numbers because 123.

should return

> "and this is not a sentence with numbers because 123.

I know that there are ways to extract digits from a string, but I am not sure how to find the indices and subsequently extract the required string. Any help is appreciated

Comment: This has a couple room for errors and unexpected input from what I can tell. For example, should sentences be separated by comma `,` as in this case, as well as dots `.` as normal? Also, how would we handle a case like `Dr. Smitty entered the room 123.` for example?

Comment: @rv.kvetch That is a good catch. I can ensure that words like Dr. Smitty will not occur. The only worry is when decimals happen. For instance, I don't want to separate "12.3 is a number" as two sentences. Otherwise, dots will only be used as a separation.

Comment: Regex is not natural language syntax aware thing. Use NLP packages.

Comment: @Tab1e please consider upvoting/accepting helpful/correct answers.it rewards people who invested time into helping you and helps future readers to find good answers quicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for the given question, but as commented, the question has room for errors and assumptions.

```
import re

test = "This is a sentence with numbers, and this is not a sentence with numbers because 123"

for t in test.split(','):
    num = re.findall(r'\d+', t)
    if num:
        print(t)
```

Comment: Is there a way to split both ',' and '.'?

Comment: Yes its possible, in that case you may need to use re.split, like re.split("[.,]", test)

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:**

> I would take the whole string, split it into substrings based on characters that indicate a new substring (like `. , ! ?`, etc..). Then scan each substring for a number and return it, only if it contains a number.
> You could also use the `re` module to split the string.

Answer (score 0):

first split text with "." ,but "1.2" will be spilted .
so we use `\.(?!\d)|(?<!\d)\.` ,it means ". that left is not a number or right is not a number"

```
import re

text = "Test 1.2,Test A.1 Test,3 Test 4."

for t in re.split(r'\.(?!\d)|(?<!\d)\.|,', text):
    num = re.findall(r'\d+', t)
    if num:
        print(t)
```

Comment: you can obviously see the OP is new to this. Please provide some context to what your regex is doing. It is even difficult for me to read, even though I know regex